# Google Analytics API. How to get the full list of profiles

Tags: objective-c, google-analytics-api

I have this line that work perfectly.

```
GTLQueryAnalytics *query = [GTLQueryAnalytics queryForDataGaGetWithIds:@"ga:66661549" startDate:@"2006-01-01" endDate:@"today" metrics:@"ga:totalEvents"];
```

Now, I need to go to thru all profiles.

I have this line who return the accounts list, but how can I get the profiles linked to the account list?

```
GTLQueryAnalytics *query = [GTLQueryAnalytics queryForManagementAccountsList];
```

Big thanks!

[EDIT]

I've found that I can do the following.  But this "cost" a lot of request.  Any better way?

(1) Query for all management accounts

```
[GTLQueryAnalytics queryForManagementAccountsList]
```

(2) Based on (1), query for all web properties

```
[GTLQueryAnalytics queryForManagementWebpropertiesListWithAccountId:XYZ]
```

(3) Based on (2), query for all website profiles

```
[GTLQueryAnalytics queryForManagementProfilesListWithAccountId:XYZ webPropertyId:ABC]
```

Comment: There is no better way that's how you have to do it

Answer (score 2):

Just found a nice trick!  And work great.  Hope it help someone.

```
GTLQueryAnalytics *query = [GTLQueryAnalytics queryForManagementProfilesListWithAccountId:@"~all" webPropertyId:@"~all"];
```